# How can i used phonegap functions like window.open in wikitude

Tags: javascript, cordova, wikitude

I have code in phonegap. What I'm trying to do is when the video is finished playing, it will call the window.open function in phonegap and redirect it to another page.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can someone help us.

Answer (score 0):

Although also JS based Wikitude's AR-View is isolated from the PhoneGap features.
You may define urlListeners to interact between PhoneGap and AR-View, but there is no way to combine Wikitude's and PhoneGap's JavaScript features in one html/js file.

Kind regards.

Find details around PhoneGap and Augmented Reality here
http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using architectsdk://.

- First set a listener via **app.wikitudePlugin.setOnUrlInvokeCallback** before creating wikitude world.

  ```
  var app = {
  // Define other functions like device onDeviceReady, onDeviceNotSupportedCallback
  // Add a listener before creating world
  onDeviceSupportedCallback: function() {

      //Set listener
      app.wikitudePlugin.setOnUrlInvokeCallback(app.onURLInvoked);

      // Create the world
      WikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld("www/world.html");
  },

  // This listener will be invoked everytime you call document.location = architectsdk://.. in ARchitectWorld
  onURLInvoked: function(url) {       
      var scheme = 'architectsdk://';
      if (url.search(scheme) === 0) {
          // Remove architectsdk://from string and evaluate function
          var func = decodeURIComponent(url.substr(scheme.length));
          eval(func);
      }       
  },
  ```

  };
- Then call listener with **document.location = architectsdk://**

  ```
  $('a').click(function() {
  var func = encodeURIComponent("window.open('"+this.href+"','_system');");
  document.location = "architectsdk://" + func;
  return false;
  ```

  });